# Story including gene-splicing to give humans photosynthesis capability

Tags: story-identification, books

This story had a superb plot device - a gene modification technology which gave humans chloroplasts (in their hair and skin) which allowed them to photosynthesise simply by lying in the sun.

As a political tool, this disconnected the poor from dependency on food manufacturers, and also dramatically reduced the workforce (as many would just lie around enjoying the free food from the Sun.)

But I can't remember the name, or even the author (although my subconscious keeps coming up with Charlie Stross...)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Green_Leopard_Plague?

Comment: Not that @Valorum, but that looks interesting, so I may have to read it too

Comment: I also thought of TGLP first, but then thought I remembered a second story with this theme, perhaps in one of Hartwell's Year's Best SF collections?  But not the title, unfortunately.

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3362310-sugar-in-the-air

Comment: lol - nope. I'm hunting through my SF collections as we speak. It must be here...

Comment: The math doesn't actually work out unless you assume a lot more efficiency than plants actually obtain. It can help extend the survivable fast, but won't replace food without some wizardry beyond just green people. None the less examples abound as  window dressing (mostly in short fiction, but Scalzi's *Old Man's War* universe has them.

Comment: Not the story you're looking for, but [The Goliath Stone](https://www.amazon.com/Goliath-Stone-Larry-Niven/dp/0765333236/) features skin photosynthesis among other wonders.

Comment: [Knights of Sidonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_of_Sidonia) had photosynthesis-people in it. I only watched the anime, but maybe you're thinking of the manga?

Comment: @Valorum I'm fairly sure your 'food for the first time' story is "Stuffing" by Jerry Oltion (and it's a great little short story). I'm fairly sure this isn't the one but I've posted it as a possible answer to rule it out.

Comment: @Tardigrade - I've removes it as a comment since it is, as you've pointed out, quite spoilerish

Comment: WRT the story itself, it would sure suck to have skin with photosynthesis, then find out you're allergic to the sun ... argh. ;-)

Comment: For what it's worth, no amount of gene splicing could ever give humans chloroplasts.  The chloroplasts, like mitochondria, began as separate organisms that became endosymbionts of eukaryotic cells.  The reproduce by fission on their own and retain a small amount of their own DNA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are looking for  [Beggars and Choosers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beggars_and_Choosers_(novel)) by Nancy Kress.

It is the second book in The Sleepless series about genetically engineered children bred to not need sleep.  They modify their own children and others with additional genetic modifications including the photosynthesis you mention.

Comment: Not quite. The Beggars do not have photosynthesis, that's in the "help package" the Sleepless Miranda Sharifi and her team develop for the downtrodden masses. But the story is, indeed, *Beggars and Choosers*.

Answer (score 2):

"Stuffing" by Jerry Oltion, first published in The Mammoth Book of Extreme Science Fiction in 2006, is a humorous short story in which people have been modified to be able to acquire their entire calorific requirements via photosynthesis and nobody eats at all, or even remembers what eating was. The protagonist begins researching the ancient festival of Thanksgiving/Christmas (from memory, he confuses or combines the two) and via this discovers the curious ancient tradition of eating food. He persuades his household replicator to produce various ingredients and equipment, they prepare a traditional dinner, and enjoy it so much they can't understand why anyone stopped eating.

> The story ends by foreshadowing the characters' imminent bowel movements, which they have no experience of (or relevant furnishings for) so everything is about to go horribly wrong.

Thanks to @Valorum for the partial recollection of this story, which prompted this answer.

I'm not convinced it's a perfect match to your question since it sounds like in yours photosynthesis is mainly used by poor people, but since it's been mentioned in the comments above it's worth ruling it out. I have come across other stories using this device but can't remember details (I was recently rereading TMBoESF so although I don't have it handy I can still remember it fairly clearly).

Answer (score 2):

Late late LATE to this post but I just spent about an hour looking for this book, stumbled across this question and an hour later suddenly remembered the title - 'By Light Alone' by Adam Roberts.

It was on my bookshelf for years, never got around to reading it before it was lost, but I distinctly remember the Art Deco cover and "light" in the title.

Comment: Can you add details? Like try to specify how/why this matches the OP's criteria. Did it have gene modification? etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Child Garden by Geoff Ryman perhaps?

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/258096.The_Child_Garden

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how _The Child Garden_ matches the story described in the question. Copying and pasting the Goodreads synopsis into your answer would be helpful too. [This post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9445/122024) offers guidance on how to write a good story ID answer. You might also want to take the [tour], to learn more about the site in general.

Comment: Also worth reading other answers before posting - I already accepted Josh's answer as it is the correct one.